# Searching for a specific object in an ArrayList

Tags: java, search

Is this an efficient way to search for a specific object in an ArrayList?

Product is the superclasS. Mobo, CPU, RAM, GPU... are the subclasses.
ArrayList(called stock) stores Product objects. I consider that they key i am searching is found when class and the attribute "model"(you can see the getter of the attribute in my code) are matching.

```
public static boolean checkAvailability(ArrayList<Product> stock, Product product) {
    boolean found = false;
    for(Product p: stock) {
        if(p instanceof Mobo && (product.getModel() == p.getModel())) {
            found = true;
            break;
        };
        if(p instanceof CPU && (product.getModel() == p.getModel())) {
            found = true;
            break;
        };
        if(p instanceof GPU && (product.getModel() == p.getModel())) {
            found = true;
            break;
        };
        if(p instanceof RAM && (product.getModel() == p.getModel())) {
            found = true;
            break;
        };
        if(p instanceof Monitor && (product.getModel() == p.getModel())) {
            found = true;
            break;
        };
        if(p instanceof Keyboard && (product.getModel() == p.getModel())) {
            found = true;
            break;
        };
        if(p instanceof Mouse && (product.getModel() == p.getModel())) {
            found = true;
            break;
        };
        if(p instanceof Printer && (product.getModel() == p.getModel())) {
            found = true;
            break;
        };
    };
    return found;
}
```

Comment: "efficient" in what way? performance? memory? lines-of-code?

Comment: @SharonBenAsher Anything. Whatever i can do to improve it in any way.

Comment: soo ... why are you checking the specific type of the product you're currently examining?

Comment: Do you need to check the types of products? Is it not sufficient to check `getModel()`?

Comment: When you write in your description that the classes need to match, what exactly do you mean? I would have thought that it means the class of the search key needs to match the class of the item in the stock, is this correct? Because that's not what your code does, and I'm not sure if this is a mistake, or whether I have just misunderstood your description.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your code is very wet (the opposite of DRY). It repeats a *lot*. Let's start with what you're trying to achieve:

1. You have an `ArrayList` of `Product`s.
2. You want `checkAvailability` to return true if any `Product` within the given `ArrayList` has the same model and type of the given `Product`.

The way you've implemented this, with `instanceof` checks, is IMO not ideal. Instead, let's modify the `Product` class to have a custom `equals()` method to compare equality of `Product`s; we can store the equality logic inside of the `Product` class so it's reusable.

The `equals()` method on an Object, by default, will act similar to `==` - that is, it will compare referential equality, but it's a common idiom to override this method to compare logical equality instead.

```
class Product {
    ...

    @Override()
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        // This is unavoidable, since equals() must accept an Object and not something more derived
        if (other instanceof Product) {
            // Note that I use equals() here too, otherwise, again, we will check for referential equality.
            // Using equals() here allows the Model class to implement it's own version of equality, rather than
            // us always checking for referential equality.
            Product otherProduct = (Product) other;
            return otherProduct.getModel().equals(this.getModel());
        }

        return false;
    } 
}
```

Of course, this does lose the `instanceof` checking in your `checkAvailability` method, but you can easily reintroduce something similar by overriding `equals()` in the subclasses of `Product` if you wanted to reintroduce this check (Spoiler: You probably don't! Don't compare types unless you have to). At the very least, try to move equality logic to an `equals()` method on a class rather than comparing equality outside of the class. Encapsulation and reusability is always nice!

With this override, we can simplify `checkAvailability` to the following:

```
public static boolean checkAvailability(ArrayList<Product> stock, Product product) {
    for (Product p : stock) {
        if (p.equals(product)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Which can be simplified to use Java streams if you'd like.

```
public static boolean checkAvailability(ArrayList<Product> stock, Product product) {
    return stock.stream()
                .anyMatch(p -> p.equals(product));
}
```

Or, even better, we can make the required type less specific:

```
public static boolean checkAvailability(Collection<Product> stock, Product product) {
    return stock.stream()
                .anyMatch(p -> p.equals(product));
}
```

As an aside: it is generally good practice to reimplement `hashCode()` if you reimplement `equals()`. Without having more knowledge of your solution, it's difficult for me to tell you how to do this, but I would recommend you do it if you end up using my suggestions.

Another side note: If you find yourself making lots of comprehensions like this, I would recommend having `checkAvailability` accept a `Stream<Product>` instead of `Collection<Product>` so as to avoid creating multiple streams.

Comment: If you already use `equals()`, it is sufficent to check `stock.contains(product)` as long as the collection does not rely on hashCodes, i.e. the collection is a list. After implementation of `hashCode()` this will work for any collection.

Comment: it is beyond good practice to override both hashcode and equals if you ever intend storing your items in things like hashmap or hashset, as you could end up with multiple items that are all equal in the set/map but have different object identity.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265503/why-do-i-need-to-override-the-equals-and-hashcode-methods-in-java

Comment: The most generic form of the last signature could/should be `Collection<? extends Product>` (so that you could pass in a `ArrayList<RAM>`, for example)

Comment: You can simplify the stream further: `return stock.stream().anyMatch(product::equals);`

Answer (score 8):

1. there is a redundant semi-colon ';' at the end of every if and at the end of the loop (basically after closing curly braces)
2. code to the inteface: the method should accept an argument of `List` type. that way callers may choose which list implementation to use (e.g. `LinkedList`)
3. the boolean variable is redundant.  you can immediately return `true` if match is found, otherwise return `false`

   ```
       if(p instanceof Mobo && (product.getModel() == p.getModel())) {
           return true;
       }
       ...
   }  // closing the for loop
   return false;
   ```
4. the sequence of if questions can easily be collapsed into one condition:

   ```
   if ((p instanceof Mobo || p instanceof CPU || ...) && product.getModel() == p.getModel()) {
       return true;
   }
   ```
5. but instead of questioning against individual types, you can put them all in a collection and query on containment:

   ```
   private static Set<Class<? extends Product>> productTypes;  // class variable
   static {  // static constructor
      productTypes.add(Mobo.class);
      productTypes.add(CPU.class);
   }

   // inside the method        
   if (productTypes.contains(p.getClass()) && product.getModel() == p.getModel()) {
       return true;
   }
   ```

Comment: In case some of the classes can be supertypes of `p.getClass()` I would recommend `productTypes.stream().anyMatch(c -> c.isAssignableFrom(p.getClass()))`

Answer (score 2):

The `instanceof` keyword is usually a sign of bad inheritance (Liskov's substitution principle) and I do not recommend to use that.

Beside that, I do not understand that data structure of your stock information.

Why not something like this?

```
boolean stockAvailable(Map<ProductId, Integer> stock, Product product) {
    if(!stock.contains(product.getProductId()) { // ... guard
        return false;
    }

    return stock.get(product.getProductId()) > 0;
}
```

Comment: I'd say that's an outdated viewpoint. It's a valid inversion (thought not likely warranted here)  but Java makes it ugly. Visitors are far worse however.

Comment: @AluanHaddad: Nah, it ain't. If you introduce a new subtype, you have to change other code. If you introduce a subtype which extends a subtype, it gets even worse and very error prone. That's Liskov and SRP violated...

Comment: only if you don't handle the base case

Comment: don't you miss a `!` in that if? `if( ! stock.contains(...){ return false; }`

Comment: @Imus : Oops, yeah, fixed it, thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 2):

You ignored my comment asking for clarification, so I'll just assume that I was right in thinking that your code doesn't actually do what you intend it to do. You write that, for a match, the class and model needs to match, but your code compares only the model of the search key with that of the items in the stock. It doesn't check whether an item from the stock has the same class as the search key, it just ascertains that the class of the stock item is one of several classes, regardless of whether this class is also the class of the search key.

In fact, your verbal description of the code is very simple, and the translation into code should not be much more complex:

```java
public static boolean checkAvailability(List<Product> stock, Product product) {
    for(Product p: stock) {
        if (product.getModel() == p.getModel()
                && product.getClass() == p.getClass()) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

You can also use a stream instead:

```java
public static boolean checkAvailability(List<Product> stock, Product product) {
    return stock.stream().anyMatch((Product p) ->
            product.getModel() == p.getModel()
                    && product.getClass() == p.getClass());
}
```

Note that, unlike `instanceof`, this only checks the classes for equality and returns `false` if one class is a subclass of the other. If you want to consider subclasses as well, you can use `Class.isAssignableFrom(Class)`.

You should also be aware that, unless `Product.getModel()` returns a primitive type, you are comparing the models based on reference equality rather than comparing their contents. I don't know what type `Product.getModel()` returns, but even if it only returns a simple `String`, `==` will not consider the contents of the Strings but only check whether the two variables reference the same object (which might not necessarily be the case even if the String's contents are identical), so you would need to use `equals(Object)` if you want to compare the contents of the two Strings.

Comment: Yes. You are right.